# What makes two solutions distinct in the Vinogradov mean value?

Tags: diophantine-equations, analytic-number-theory

As in e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vinogradov%27s_mean-value_theorem, the *Vinogradov mean value* $J_{s,k}(X)$ is defined to be the 'number of solutions' to the system of $k$ simultaneous Diophantine equations in $2s$ variables given by 
$$x_1^j+x_2^j+\ldots+x_s^j=y_1^j+y_2^j+\ldots+y_s^j$$
for $1\leq j \leq k$, with 
$$1\leq x_i,y_i \leq X.$$
What I don't understand is exactly what counts as distinct solutions. Clearly, given a solution one can swaps the $x_i$ with the $y_i$ or permute the $x_i$ or $y_i$ to get 'new' solutions. But the trivial lower bound for this quantity is supposedly $\lfloor X\rfloor^s$, 'taking $x_i=y_i$', suggesting that these solutions don't count, but doesn't this still count permutations of the $x_i$? I'm unsure exact what the 'number of solutions' means here.

Comment: The trivial lower bound is $C X^s$ for some constant $C$ (independent of $X$) that we don't care about. You need to investigate the analytic formula $J_{s,k}(X)=\int_{[0,1)^k}|f_k(\mathbf\alpha;X)|^{2s}d\mathbf\alpha$

Comment: @reuns But what is the definition of 'distinct solutions' here?

Comment: The one for which $$J_{s,k}(X)=\int_{[0,1)^k}|f_k(\mathbf\alpha;X)|^{2s}d\mathbf\alpha$$ is true

Comment: I get that that's an indirect answer, but surely there's an easy, clearcut answer to my question. I will establish that formula as an exercise later on (in an example sheet), but for now I'm just trying to understand the relevant content and would simply like to quickly know what makes solutions count as 'distinct' in this system of equations.